# C# winform app - generate numbers and add to list, then plot to chart

Tags: c#

I have a similar app in Python, but I am struggling with implementing it in C# since I'm new to the language and syntax.

I want to simulate a physical process, using a mathematical model for it. I will use a WinForm app to plot the data in a chart, with the process data being generated from the mathematical model simulation. This mathematical model is implemented as a separate class, and in the main "Form1.cs" class it will be called with regular intervals using a Timer object to retrieve new values by calling a method of the Process class.

My main issues so far should be rather basic to the more experienced here; I need a method receives an input control signal u (variable, not constant), uses it for calculating the new value (using previous value in a list), then adding new process value to the list and returning both the new list for plotting, and the new process value to be saved to a database (insert a new entry).

Below code is what I have so far:

```
namespace Process
{
    class Simulator
    {
        public List<double> TemperatureList { get; set; }
        public double ControlSignal { get; set; }

        /// Process parameters:
        static private double Kh = 3.5;
        static private double theta_constant = 23.0;
        static private double theta_delay = 3.0;
        static private double temp_env = 20.0;
        static private double t_step = 1;


        //private double u_signal { get { return ControlSignal; } }

        public double Temperature()
        {
            this.ControlSignal = u_signal;
            public double T_k = TemperatureList[TemperatureList.Count - 1];
            // Euler forward integration (Euler step):
            public double calc = (1 / theta_constant) * ((temp_env) + Kh * u_signal);
            // Calculate next point
            public double T_kp1 = T_k + t_step*calc;

            TemperatureList.Add(T_kp1);

            return T_kp1;

        }
    }
}
```

The above Class Method "Temperature" throws a bunch of errors. Any pointers on how to properly structure the code to behave as I need it to? My main thought is upon calling the Temperature method for a given instance of the class, it will calculate the next process value (temperature), add it to the list of previous calculated temperatures, and then returns the newest value. The List can then also be used to plot data in the chart.

The ControlSignal double is also a variable that will be changed by another class (a controller), so not sure how to use that for the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the scope declaration of variables in your method.  You cannot use public keyword in method block.

```
public double Temperature()
{
    double T_k = TemperatureList.Last();
    double calc = (temp_env + Kh * u_signal) / theta_constant;
    double T_kp1 = T_k + t_step * calc;
    TemperatureList.Add(T_kp1);
    return T_kp1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will read up on C# syntax asap. This fixed it, and I understand how to proceed with the remaining code as well :)